# set the thumb in seekbar below horizontal bar android

Tags: android

Does someone know the property to set the thumb below the seekbar within the xml or programmatically, please? I need this in my application

```java
SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);
seekBar.setMax(15);
seekBar.setIndeterminate(true);
seekBar.setMinimumWidth(200);

ShapeDrawable thumb = new ShapeDrawable( new OvalShape() );
thumb.getPaint().setColor( 0x00FF00 );
thumb.setIntrinsicHeight( 80 );
thumb.setIntrinsicWidth( 30 );

seekBar.setThumb(thumb);
seekBar.setProgress(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be late...
But u can create the image in this way....
make a rectangle image in which top part is transparent and in the bottom part image will come....so user will see it like image is at bottom part of horizontal..